# How can i compare an int pointer with a char pointer?

Tags: c

In my code i'm trying to do a comparison between an int pointer and a char pointer. The char pointer is supposed to hold an integer after i strrchr the full string. I then want to see if the integer is larger than another integer that is stored in an int pointer. Using strcmp, or just doing >= will give me a warning.
Assume that an int will always be present after the semicolon.

```
typedef struct songInfo
{
 int* ratingScore;
 char songName[80];
 struct songInfo *prev;
 struct songInfo *next;
 }songInfo;

int main()
{
 songInfo *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;
 ...
}


int insert(char *buffer, songInfo **head, songInfo **tail)
{
 ...
 char* rating = strrchr(song, ';');
 rating++;
 if ((*head)->ratingScore >= rating)
 ...
}
```

Comment: What do you want to compare pointed objects as? As integers?

Comment: Yes, as integers @HolyBlackCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to convert the string representation of the integer(the one pointed to by `rating`) that was *typed into* the string to a second integer to compare its value to the integer pointed to by int pointer you mention.

You may use a function such as `sscanf` to read the string representation into an integer and you can compare the value read with the one pointed to by the integer pointer. Below is a sample code that may more or less achieve what you are attempting to do.

```
int tmp;
sscanf(rating+1, "%d", &tmp); // +1 is to skip the ';' character
if( *(*head)->ratingScore >= tmp)
{
    ...
}
```

Notice that the dereferencing operator for ratingScore was added due to your mention of the type of ratingScore being an int* in the comments to my answer. (Also note that I do not understand *why* you would keep it as an int*, but the code above should satisfy your constraints nonetheless)

[Here](http://ideone.com/z0Dhyh)'s a sample usage of this idea at work.

Comment: I think i might have tried this by using atoi(). However, i was still getting a incompatible type error when comparing the result.

Comment: @asa What is the exact type of ratingScore?

Comment: @asa if it is an int* you need to dereference it before using this. But if it is an int, I believe you can just use it as it is.

Comment: @asa I added a dereference operator to turn that into an int. Now you should be able to compare the two integer values correctly.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now the program crashes.

Comment: @asa Can you add to the question the exact definition of the type of `head`?

Comment: @asa can you add the definition of songInfo to your question?

Comment: Added as much as i could remember, currently on a different device for now

Comment: @asa your sample code for the definition of songInfo does not feature a variable called ratingScore. You should update the question with the original code when you can.

Comment: @asa I tried my implementation on ideone, and added its link to my answer. It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of of course you cannot compare 2 pointers of different types, but anyway it seems to me that you are more trying to compare the values pointed than the pointers. As @ilim said, you want to use `strtol(*rating, NULL, 0)` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

rating points to ';'
rating+1 points to your integer let's say A
A = atoi(rating+1)
So here it goes:

```
char* rating = strrchr(song, ';');
if ((*head)->ratingScore >= atoi(rating+1))
```

Now that you showed that ratingScore is not an integer but a pointer to an integer you just need to dereference that pointer. So here it goes:

```
char* rating = strrchr(song, ';');
if (*((*head)->ratingScore) >= atoi(rating+1))
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I did do: rating++;